# Заменить значения елементов дерева, которие состоят из одинаковых цифр

Tags: c#, бинарное-дерево

Как заменить нулями повторяющиеся элементы в бинарном дереве?

```
`public class Leaf
```

{

```
public int Data;
public Leaf Left;
public Leaf Right;

public Leaf(int data)
{
    Data = data;
    Left = Right = null;
}

public void AddNode(int data){
    if (data <= Data) {
        if (Left == null)
            Left = new Leaf(data);
        else
            Left.AddNode(data);
    }
    else if (data >= Data) {
        if (Right == null)
            Right = new Leaf(data);
        else
            Right.AddNode(data);
    }
}
class BinaryTree
```

{

```
public static void PostPrintTree(Leaf root)
{
    if (root != null)
    {
        PostPrintTree(root.Left);
        Console.Write($"{root.Data}   ");

        PostPrintTree(root.Right);
    }
}

public static void ChangeTree(Leaf root)
{
    if (root != null)
    {
        ChangeTree(root.Left);
        if (root.Data < 0)
            root.Data = 0;
        ChangeTree(root.Right);
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    Console.Write(" Input the size of the tree: ");
    int rootData = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Leaf tree = new Leaf(rootData);

    for (int i = 0; i < rootData; i++)
    {
        Console.Write($" Element {i + 1} = ");
        int value = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        tree.AddNode(value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\n Output of tree elements");
    PostPrintTree(tree);
    Console.WriteLine();

    ChangeTree(tree);
    Console.WriteLine();
    PostPrintTree(tree);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

}

Например, если элементы будут такие:
5 3 4 3 7 6 3

На выходе должно получиться так:
5 0 4 0 7 6 0

Comment: Что именно не получается?

Comment: Дело в том, что я просто не знаю, как это зделать, получилось только заменить все отрицательние елементы, но я не знаю как сравнивать одинаковие элементы

Comment: В упорядоченном бинарном дереве все одинаковые элементы будут рядом. При обходе дерева нужно проверять родителя на равенство. Для этого достаточно при обработке дочерних передавать значение родителя. Но в том коде который вы привели одинаковых элементов не будет, так нет для них условия в AddNode.

Comment: Сейчас уже можно добавлять одинаковые элементы, но я не совсем понял, как имено проверять на равенство, и передать значение родителя.